# Number of samples required for an event to occur with a given confidence level

Tags: probability, statistics

Say I have a continuous random variable $X$ that is distributed according to a uniform distribution $U\left(0,m\right)$. How many samples, $N$, must I draw so that, with 95% confidence, at least one sample falls in the interval $\left[ a-\delta, a \right]$ and at least one sample falls in the interval $\left[a,a+\delta\right]$?

In other words, I want to know how many samples, $N$, to draw in order to estimate the value $a$ to within an amount $\delta$ with 95% confidence. Assume that I have a way of knowing whether a sample falls below or above $a$, e.g. I have some function $Y(x) = \begin{cases} 1\ \text{for} x < a \\ 0\ \text{for} x > a \end{cases}$, that I can use to test.

I have thought about it a bunch of different ways and keep getting different answers. Here are things I've tried:

1. The probability of a sample falling in the first interval is $\frac{\delta}{m}$. The probability of a sample falling in the second interval is, likewise, $\frac{\delta}{m}$. The probability of both happening is, then, ${\left(\frac{\delta}{m}\right)}^2$. Then the number of samples I need to draw should be $N=\frac{0.95}{{\left(\frac{\delta}{m}\right)}^2}$. This gives something sensible in that as $N \rightarrow \infty$ as $\delta \rightarrow 0$. But I've confused myself thinking about it different ways and getting different answers so I'm not sure this is right.
2. Say I draw $N$ samples, and $N_1$ of them fall in the first interval, and $N_2$ fall in the second. The probability of at least one falling in the first and one falling in the second (in the limit of large $N$) should be equal to the number of ways I can pick 2 of my samples such that one falls in the first interval and the other falls in the second divided by the total number of ways I can pick two samples. This gives me $\frac{N_1 N_2}{\binom{N}{2}}$, but for large $N$ we have that $N_1 = N_2 \approx \frac{N\delta}{m}$. Substituting and evaluating the binomial gives $\frac{N^2 {\left(\frac{\delta}{m}\right)}^2}{\frac{N\left(N-1\right)}{2}}$. We can set this equal to 0.95 and solve for $N$,  and we get a quadratic equation $\left(1-A\right)N^2 + AN=0$, with $A \equiv \frac{0.95m}{2\delta}$, which has the solution $N={\left(1-\frac{2\delta}{0.95m}\right)}^{-1}$. However, this can't be right, since as $\delta \rightarrow 0$ we have $N \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: What is the meaning of this value $a$ that you want to estimate? How could drawing any number of samples from a known distribution $U(0,m)$ help you estimate $a$?

Comment: By the way, the word "confidence" in the first paragraph makes no sense in that context. The word "probability" would fit there.

Comment: I can sample values $\left\{X_1,X_2,...,X_N\right\}$, but I actually observe $\left\{Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_N\right\}$, where $Y\!\left(X\right)$ is defined above. At a certain value $x=a$ I find that there is a step in the value of $y$ from $y =1$ to $y=0$. I want to estimate what the value of $a$ is based on random observations $\left\{Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_N\right\}$. I want to know how many observations, $N$, are necessary to estimate $a$ to within $\pm \delta$ of its true value with a confidence level of 95%

Comment: I think I see. The way I read the question at first, I though $Y$ was a tool you proposed to use in order to find out something about $a$ or even $X$. My understanding now is that you want to estimate the unknown parameter of the function $Y$. In that light, the second paragraph makes a coherent question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of the question, you have a variable $Y(X)$
that depends on the uniform random variable $X \sim U(0,m)$,
such that $Y(X) = 1$ precisely when $X > a$ and $Y(X)=0$ otherwise.
I'm also assuming you can measure $Y$ but not $X$ each time you take a sample.
(If you observe and measure the values of $X$ and $Y$ simultaneously
then the approach is different, of course; see below the line.)

The variable $Y$ has the distribution of a Bernoulli variable with
parameter $p = 1 - \frac am$. That is,

$$\begin{eqnarray}
P(Y=0) &=& \frac am, \\
P(Y=1) &=& 1 - \frac am.
\end{eqnarray}$$

There are known methods for estimating the parameter of a Bernoulli variable
with a desired confidence.
There is some discussion of this in
[Monte Carlo method error in Bernoulli random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/622818/139123)
or [Confidence interval for estimating probability of a biased coin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/888562/139123),
although there are surely other places you might find the answer
to that question.

Working backward from $p = 1 - \frac am$, we have $a = m(1 - p)$.
So when you have enough samples to estimate $p$ such that 
$p \in [\hat p - \epsilon, \hat p + \epsilon]$ with $95$% confidence,
you also have
$$a \in [m(1 - (\hat p + \epsilon)), m(1 - (\hat p - \epsilon))]
= [m(1 - \hat p) - m\epsilon, m(1 - \hat p) + m\epsilon].$$
(Notice that the upper bound of $p$ gives the lower bound of $a$ 
and vice versa.)
So you need to take samples until you can state the confidence
interval around $\hat p$ with $\epsilon \leq \frac \delta m$
and then you have $a \in [\hat a - \delta, \hat a+\delta]$
where $\hat a = m(1 - \hat p).$

---

If you are observing pairs of values $(X,Y)$ then in fact you do just need
to get one $X$ value in the interval $(a-\delta,a)$
and one in the interval $(a, a+\delta).$

The probability that a given $X$ is *not* in $(a-\delta,a)$
is $1 - \frac\delta m.$ Likewise the probability 
that $X$ is *not* in $(a, a+\delta).$
Let $A$ be the event that there is a sample with $X \in (a-\delta,a)$,
and $B$ be the event that there is a sample with $X \in (a, a+\delta).$
Then after $N$ trials,
$$P\left(A^C\right) = P\left(B^C\right) = \left(1 - \frac\delta m\right)^N.$$
The probability that a single $X$ will not be in 
$ (a-\delta,a) \cup (a, a+\delta)$ is $1 - 2\frac\delta m$,
so
$$P\left(A^C \cap B^C\right) =  \left(1 - 2\frac\delta m\right)^N.$$
The probability of interest to you is

$$\begin{eqnarray}
P(A \cap B) &=& 1 - P\left(A^C \cup B^C\right) \\
&=& 1 - (P\left(A^C\right) + P\left(B^C\right) - P\left(A^C \cap B^C\right)) \\
&=& 1 - P\left(A^C\right) - P\left(B^C\right) + P\left(A^C \cap B^C\right) \\
&=& 1 - 2 \left(1 - \frac\delta m\right)^N + \left(1 - 2\frac\delta m\right)^N.
\end{eqnarray}$$

You need to find $N$ large enough so that $P(A \cap B) \geq 0.95.$

---

**Update:** It might also be interesting to consider what happens if you
get observations with $X_i = a - 1.7\delta$ and $X_j = a + 0.1\delta$.
If you use this to make the reasonable estimate,
$\hat a = \frac12(X_i + X_j) = a - 0.9\delta,$ which is within $\delta$
of the correct answer, and moreover since $X_j - X_i = 1.8\delta$
you *know* that your estimate is within the interval $[a-\delta, a+\delta]$.
So by this reasoning the number of trials, $N$, computed above
seems to be larger than necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. How would the solution be different if I can measure both $X$ and $Y$? (That is actual situation that I find myself in).

Comment: It occurred to me after posting the answer that that was probably what you meant. I've added to the answer to try to cover that version of the problem.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, although it then occurred to me that one could get to the $95$% chance of estimating $a$ to the desired accuracy in somewhat fewer trials. But at least the $N$ in the answer is an upper bound!